# Why is 'state' undefined when I try to display user input in final step of React app?

Tags: reactjs, forms, variables, input

I would like to allow user to see all the input values during final step but when I try to access the input value via this.state I get this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'state' of undefined

I've tried using this.props but it still comes back undefined

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

class MasterForm extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
        this.state = {
            currentStep: 1, 
            firstname: '',

        };

    }



     render() {
    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <h1>Enter Name</h1>
            <p>Step {this.state.currentStep} </p>

            <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                {/*
    render the form steps and pass required props in
  */}
                <Step1
                    currentStep={this.state.currentStep}
                    handleChange={this.handleChange}
                    firstname={this.state.firstname}


                />
                <Step2
                    currentStep={this.state.currentStep}
                />


                {this.previousButton()}
                {this.nextButton()}

            </form>

        </React.Fragment>

function Step1(props) {
    {
        if(props.currentStep !==1) {
            return null
        }
        return(
            <div className="form-group">
                <div><h2> Personal Information</h2></div>
                <label htmlFor="firstname">First Name</label>
                <input
                    className="form-control"
                    id="firstname"
                    name="firstname"
                    type="text"
                    placeholder="Enter First Name"
                    defaultValue={props.firstname}
                    onChange={props.handleChange}
                />

function Step2 (props) {

    {
        if (props.currentStep !== 2) {
            return null
        }

        return (

            <React.Fragment>

          <div> <h1> {this.state.firstname} </h1> </div>




            </React.Fragment>
        )

    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<MasterForm />, document.getElementById('Example'));
```

When user gets to Step2 I expect them to see the `firstname` data they input. Their `{this.state.firstname}`. But all I get is the error

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'state' of undefined

Comment: Where `render()` for component `MasterForm`?

Comment: Step2 is a functional component. Those don't have a state.

Comment: I don't see any way that currentStep could be changing to begin with, so I don't know how it would ever get to Step2. Not to mention, it's set to return null if not equal to 4..

Comment: Don't use `this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);`, your constructor shouldn't know which class functions exist: that's literally what the class itself is already for. Use `<form onSubmit={evt => this.handleSubmit(evt)}>` and trust React to not "rebuild" the form element, because it has no reason to (even if it ends up rebuilding one or more of the form's _children_).

Comment: Hey, I added render () way of changing current step. Thanks @AlexanderStaroselsky

Comment: Hey, I added render () way of changing current step. Thanks @RobB

Comment: There is no `this.state` in your functional component

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I made changes but it still says 'state' undefined.

Comment: hi @JohnRuddell how do I add state to functional component?

Comment: hi @PatrickHund how do I add state to functional component?

Comment: You dont, your parent has the state, pass it to the child. Its a stateless component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently the `Step2` component is trying to access `this.state.firstname`. However, this is invalid, the state is on the parent. You need to access the value from props in your Step2 component.

```
props.firstName
```

pass the value from the parent

```
<Step2
  currentStep={this.state.currentStep}
  firstName={this.state.firstName}
/>
```

then update Step2 as follows

```
function Step2 (props) {
  if (props.currentStep !== 2) {
    return null
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <h1> {props.firstname} </h1>
    </div>
  )
}
```

### Edit

It looks like you are copy pasting part of the component, in this example you omitted the handleChange function. Heres more complete solution with the parent to child communication. Also your formatting was all over the place, so i cleaned that up some too.

```
class MasterForm extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        currentStep: 1, 
        firstname: '',
    };
  }
  handleChange = (e) => {
    const {name, value} = e.target
    this.setState({[name]: value})
  }
  handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    // TODO
  }
  render() {
    const { currentStep, firstname } = this.state
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <h1>Enter Name</h1>
        <p>Step {currentStep} </p>

        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <Step1
            currentStep={currentStep}
            handleChange={this.handleChange}
            firstname={firstname}
          />
          <Step2
            currentStep={currentStep}
            firstname={firstname}
          />
          {this.previousButton()}
          {this.nextButton()}
        </form>
      </React.Fragment>
    )
  }
}

function Step1({handleChange, currentStep, firstname}) {
  if(currentStep !==1) {
    return null
  }
  return (
    <div className="form-group">
      <div><h2> Personal Information</h2></div>
      <label htmlFor="firstname">First Name</label>
      <input
          className="form-control"
          id="firstName"
          name="firstName"
          type="text"
          placeholder="Enter First Name"
          defaultValue={firstname}
          onChange={handleChange}
      />
    </div>
  )
}

function Step2 ({currentStep, firstname}) {
  if (currentStep !== 2) {
    return null
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <h1> {firstname} </h1>
    </div>
  )
}
```